# Why isn`t this method repeating forever?

Tags: java

When i was having fun i found out something weird about methods

```
public class T {
    static void m() {
        System.out.println("M");
        m1();
    }

    static void m1() {
        System.out.println("MM");
        m();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m();
    }
}
```

There are no exceptions in this code but it does not repeat for ever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code won't compile because you're calling a non-`static` method from a `static` method without a class instance.

Once you fix that, you'll end up with infinite recursion.

On a typical JVM this would lead to the code eventually running out of stack space. On a JVM that optimizes tail recursion the code would be equivalent to an infinite loop.

Comment: "*On a JVM that optimizes tail recursion the code would be equivalent to an infinite loop*" - That's interesting, can you please explain more about this? What would be the difference?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: It will run "forever", instead of running out of stack space.

Comment: Thanks. Why is this called optimization? I guess that running out of stack is the better choice since it'll indicate that there's a possible leak/error. Though it really depends of what's "better" for the programmer..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: It's also called tail call elimination. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Answer (score 1):

If you made `m` and `m1` *static*, the code will compile and you'll get infinite recursion because:

In `m` you call `m1`, and in `m1` you call `m` and in `m` you call `m1` and in `m1` you call `m` and in `m` you call `m1` and...

Answer (score 0):

It will repeat for ever if make the methods `static` or call it properly. Since the methods  are (after the edit) `static` now it will repeat for ever.